# Topic List in Autonav Block

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I'm working on a responsive navigation for a customer. I'm using concrete5.7's AutoNav block with a customized view template. The fullscreen overlay is working and lists links to the top-level pages. Under the first and second links (see attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1CQt.png), I need the following:

- First Navigation Link (Projects page): A topic_list that filters a page_list block on the Projects page.
- Second Navigation Link (Services page): A list of its direct child pages.

Should I programmatically include the topic_list Block in my AutoNav custom view? Is it possible to access and list topics from the AutoNav block? I really don't know how to approach this. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this add-on can help you: https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/mega-menu1
I didn't use or try it myself, but it seems to be possible to add stacks as submenu's. I guess these stacks could hold page_list/topic_list blocks.

Another approach could be to use page_list instead of the autonav. Create a topic structure with the same layout as your pages.

Or indeed programmatically adapt the autonav with a template, and check for level and topics to insert them as a submenu.